# Why doesn't this SQL update statement work?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I can't get this right...

I need to set `gift_id` value to NULL if `reservation_id IS NOT NULL` of the same row.

Thing that I am trying to achieve is to delete `gift_id` column of certain row if I update reservation_id column of that row.

```
CREATE TRIGGER add_reservation 
AFTER UPDATE ON [dbo].[order] 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF [reservation_id] IS NOT NULL 
        THEN SET [gift_id] = NULL 
    END IF 
END
```

Error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure add_reservation, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near 'AFTER'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure add_reservation, Line 6
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'THEN'

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure add_reservation, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near 'AFTER'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure add_reservation, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'THEN'.

Comment: I don't see a problem with your syntax.  Can you clarify the error at all?

Comment: Your syntax looks like sql-server syntax but your question is tagged as mysql? Which dbms do you use?

Comment: No, I can't. Is there any other way to change field of one row to NULL if other field of the same row is not NULL ?

Comment: I am using sql. MS SQL Server Management studio.

Comment: Sorry, if I am misunderstand something, I don't have previous experience working with sql.

Comment: There is an answer for this question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852394/instead-of-update-trigger-is-this-possible

Comment: I don't need to move data between multiple tables.

Comment: @John that answer is not for multiple tables

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an alternative in case you dont get the original code to work, this code requires a field OrderID in your table that i assumed to exist

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[order_update]
ON [dbo].[order]
FOR UPDATE

AS

UPDATE R SET R.[gift_id] = NULL
    FROM [order] O
        INNER JOIN inserted I ON I.OrderID = R.OrderID
        WHERE I.[reservation_id] IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Nop, I don't have field OderID.

Comment: Ok just replace it with your primary key for that table then, the join is to select only the rows that were updated

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
CREATE TRIGGER [DBO].[TRG_ORDER_UPDATE]
ON [TABLE_NAME]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
  BEGIN
      IF EXISTS(SELECT *
                FROM   INSERTED)
         AND EXISTS(SELECT *
                    FROM   DELETED)
; WITH TEST AS (SELECT <YOUR,COLUMNS> FROM INSERTED)
UPDATE TN SET TN.GIFT_ID = NULL 
FROM TABLE_NAME TN JOIN TEST T ON TN.(PRIMARY_COLUMN)=T.(PRIMARY_COLUMN)
WHERE T.RESERVATION_ID IS NOT NULL
END
```