# Update third table when data updated on sql view

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, view, database-trigger

I have got thease three tables:

```
CREATE TABLE tblEmployee1  
(  
 Id int Primary Key,  
 Name nvarchar(30),  
 Gender nvarchar(10),  
 DepartmentId int  
) 

CREATE TABLE tblDepartment1  
(  
 DeptId int Primary Key,  
 DeptName nvarchar(20)  
)

CREATE TABLE tblEmployee  
(  
 Id int Primary Key,  
 Name nvarchar(30),  
 Gender nvarchar(10),  
 DepartmentId int,  
 DeptName nvarchar(20)
)
```

Two of them are joined by a view:

```
Create view ViewEmployeeDetails1  
as  
Select Id, Name, Gender,DepartmentId, DeptName  
from tblEmployee1  
join tblDepartment1  
on tblEmployee1.DepartmentId = tblDepartment1.DeptId
```

I have created the trigger so that when the view is updated 
with data trigger fires and update the third table  (tblEmployee)  with data in the view wihout duplicate record.
Trigger dosent seem to insert values on to the  tblEmployee  when the view is updated. Can you please help me with the trigger dont know where it's going
worng My trigger is below Thanks in advance.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Update_Employee]
   ON  dbo.ViewEmployeeDetails1 
   INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
insert into dbo.tblEmployee  
([Id], [Name], [Gender], [DepartmentId], [DeptName])

SELECT  i.[Id],i.[Name], i.[Gender], i.[DepartmentId], i.[DeptName] 

        FROM   dbo.ViewEmployeeDetails1  t
       INNER JOIN i
        ON t.Id = i.Id 
        WHERE i.Id IS  NOT NULL
end
```

Comment: What is your use case for this? Why do you have a table that has the same data as your view?

Comment: You have an "instead of update" trigger and are then doing an `insert`.  Do you want an `instead of insert` trigger?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `DeptName` in the table, so you would seem to want:

```
insert into dbo.tblEmployee  ([Id], [Name], [Gender], [DepartmentId])
    SELECT  i.[Id], i.[Name], i.[Gender], i.[DepartmentId]
    FROM inserted i
    WHERE i.Id IS  NOT NULL
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply I tired what you suggested diddnt work

Comment: this may help.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852394/instead-of-update-trigger-is-this-possible

Comment: @Randy . . . "diddnt work" isn't very helpful.  Was there an error?  The wrong results?  The computer just crashed and you couldn't turn it back on?

Comment: Hi sorry it does not throw any errors but wouldn't update the intended table